# Processing continuous data coming through serial port

Tags: serial-port, programming-languages

I will be getting two different types of real time data continuously through serial ports. I have to process the data in real time and display it on screen in real time. I want to write a program, so that I can process the data and display it on the screen with good interface. Also, I will be getting one more set of data through NI USB 6343.

Which programming language is good, so that I can display all three sets of data in a single screen?

Comment: What languages are at your disposal?

Comment: @JimHewitt  Right now, I've got C. I'm considering to try a new language where I can get a good UI and also easy to learn.

Comment: Since you've mentioned "real-time" there times in your question, I'd suggest a deterministic language such as C or C++.  If you opt for C#, Java or any other garbage collected language, you will not get your "real-time".

Answer (score 1):

The .NET languages have a `SerialPort` class that is fairly easy to use. So, if you're on a Windows machine I would consider picking either *Visual Basic* or *C#*. They are both as easy to use as one another when it comes to serial-ports, you will just have to decide what language you like better. Coming from the C world (as I've read in your comment) you will probably be more comfortable with the syntax of C#.

Check out [this MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) of how to receive data over a serial-port in C#.